# how to enable "Show fast user switching menu as - Full Name" system wide

Tags: macos, terminal, operating-systems

I am currently using macOs High Sierra I was wondering if there is any way to enable "Show Fast User Switching menu as -Full name" system-wide via terminal. There are a lot of users using this mac and I can't enable FUS everytime a new user logs into the mac.

Any Script or command or comment would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think this is meant to be a personal preference. Why can't you leave it set the way you like for your own account, and let the other users set it as they like for their own accounts?

Comment: I find it quite weird that even though the Fast User Switching is a personal preference, it requires a admin user info to actually change it. I also want to leave it as is but the documentation for the MacOs setup requires me to enable the fast user switching.